# Windows EC2 initial config from AMI after autoscale boot up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I'm looking at autoscaling an off-the-shelf Amazon provided Windows AMI (as opposed to a custom one).

After a new instance gets booted (and before!! it gets added to load balancer), I want some initialization tasks injected and ran on the new instance (say, running a powershell script).

Secondly, the loadbalancer needs to know to only start sending requests to the new EC2 instance after this startup script has finished (not sure how to do this either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After a new instance gets booted (and before!! it gets added to load balancer), I want some initialization tasks injected and ran on the new instance (say, running a powershell script).

Take a look at [userdata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data). The long and short of it is that you can configure your instances to run a small script when they are launched, which can be used for bootstrapping.

A common practice is to just include enough code in the userdata to download a variable script from a central location (e.g. Git repository or secure S3 bucket), then execute that - this way you can version and change the actual script doing the work without having to update the userdata.

> Secondly, the loadbalancer needs to know to only start sending requests to the new EC2 instance after this startup script has finished (not sure how to do this either).

Load balancers tend to perform a kind of ping request for instances one a specified port, for a specified file to determine if it is healthy or not. I'm not sure what your Windows AMI is for, but it should work in the same way. You just need to point it at a file that will only be available once your bootstrapping is complete - i.e. maybe your bootstrapping script creates a `health.txt` file somewhere in your system with "OK" as its contents, and your load balancer can ping that file until it exists -> then it's healthy.

If you go with the above idea, ensure that `health.txt` doesn't exist as part of the AMI you use to spin auto-scaled instances up with, otherwise they will be created with that file in place and may register a false positive before your userdata/bootstrapping script has completed.

For example with a LAMP stack, it's reasonably easy to quantify this because an example userdata script might do the following:

1. Clone a Git repository
2. Clean a cache
3. Set some file/folder permissions
4. Create "health.html" in the Apache web root with "OK" as its contents, so it'll return a 200 header when pinged
5. **Start Apache**

In this example, the load balancer will ping the server's `/health.html` file every so often until it returns a 200 header, which would only occur once step 5 above has completed.

I'm sure you'll be able to work out a similar fit for your Windows AMI.

Answer (score 2):

You can run initialization tasks through powershell in UserData section with 
`<powershell>./yourscript</powershell>`
And, assuming you are using ELB, you can set your 'ping target' to point to a file which is created once the userdata scripts are executed successfully. Until then, ELB won't send traffic to your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Autoscaling will add to the ELB automatically for you: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/autoscaling-load-balancer.html